# Merge two json files into a single file Python

Tags: python, json, rest, pagination

I'm calling a paginated API and storing the data of different pages into separate files. The two files are added below.

file1.json

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Bluth",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Janet",
        "last_name": "Weaver",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Emma",
        "last_name": "Wong",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Eve",
        "last_name": "Holt",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Morris",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tracey",
        "last_name": "Ramos",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"
    }]
}
```

File2.json

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [{
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Byron",
        "last_name": "Fields",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Edwards",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Rachel",
        "last_name": "Howell",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }]
}
```

I want to merge these two files and specifically the data fields so that the result show be something like this
output.json

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Bluth",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Janet",
        "last_name": "Weaver",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Emma",
        "last_name": "Wong",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Eve",
        "last_name": "Holt",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Morris",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tracey",
        "last_name": "Ramos",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Lawson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Lindsay",
        "last_name": "Ferguson",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tobias",
        "last_name": "Funke",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Byron",
        "last_name": "Fields",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Edwards",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Rachel",
        "last_name": "Howell",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }]
}
```

What should be the approach? There are no rules here. The data present in the data field should just keep appending if there are more files added.

Comment: Do you need to append only the data field?

Comment: Yes. The output.json file will keep appending the data field from different files as you can see in the example. File 1 consists data from id 1-6 and file 2 consists data from id 7-12 which are then appended inside an output file.

Comment: Is there any rule that duplicate ID should not be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, Make sure to use different file handler Objects..

```
import json
with open('file1.json') as f:
    data1 = json.load(f)

with open('file2.json') as f1:
    data2 = json.load(f1)

data1['data'].extend(data2['data']) # Modified

with open('output.json','w') as out:
    json.dump(data1,out)
```

Better Approach,

```
import glob
import json

def processFiles():
    Files = glob.glob('Files/*.json')
    for i,singleFile in enumerate(Files):
        if i==0:
            with open(singleFile) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
        else:
            with open(singleFile) as f1:
                data['data'].extend(json.load(f1)['data'])
    return data

 
with open('output.json','w') as out:
    json.dump(processFiles(),out)
```

Comment: I'm only getting the file 2 data and not file 1. I have used different file handler objects.

Comment: Can you check it now?

Comment: Great anything else needed?

Comment: Is there any way that we can use a for loop to specify multiple files in one go so that we won't open single files every time and read them?

Comment: If you need can I add it?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: Please check whether the better approach works perfectly or not..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extend` to extend a list with another list:

```
import json

with open('json1.json') as json_file:
    json1 = json.load(json_file)

with open('json2.json') as json_file:
    json2 = json.load(json_file)

json1['data'].extend(json2['data'])
```

Or create an empty list to which you extend all lists in `data` if you want to store them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
import json

with open("file1.json") as fo:
    data1 = json.load(fo)

with open("file2.json") as fo:
    data2 = json.load(fo)

data1.update(data2)

with open("fileout.json", "w") as fo:
    json.dump(data1, fo)
```